# Add a custom badge on segmented control

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, badge

I've created a custombagde by using from custom badge 2.0.  However I got the following problem after I switched to second active segment, would anyone help me on it?

Original

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Can you share your control with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you’re adding the badge as a subview of the segmented control, and switching the control’s value reorders its subviews in such a way that one of the segments is covering your badge. Two possible solutions:

- Add the badge to the segmented control’s superview rather than the control itself
- In whatever IBAction method you have the control targeting, call `[theControl bringSubviewToFront:theBadgeView];`

Comment: My segmented control was ride on a navigation controller, could you suggest how to add the badge on it's superview?